# Strange IDE behaviour with a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running Vista SP2 : Python 3.3.5

I have a fairly large .py file (~11k lines) which I'm working on. I recently installed pyscripter and have been using it without issue for a week or so. But yesterday I went into pyscripter and as soon as I added a single new character to the file I got an "Out Of Memory" error. Sure enough it had maxed out all 2GB of ram on my laptop. I tried opening the file in IDLE, and although I could edit the file it would freeze up whenever I tried to run it. However in PythonWin the file opens and runs just fine. I commented out the function that I had last changed wondering if my code was causing the issue, but pyscripter and IDLE are still acting the same.

Anyone experience this before? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its to do with the way the GUI opens and displays the file, as i believe IDLE loads the whole thing into RAM when you open it, so the only way to get around that without changing your file would be to add more RAM, a more sensible approach would be to break up your file into smaller chunks, then add import statements at the top of the main file.

This also means that your file can be made easier to work with (assuming you break it up into sensible chunks where the functions are related in each file)

if you are worried about what will happen if you try to compile/package it up for use on other computers, i do this all the time with cx_freeze with no problems.

James

Comment: I can understanding why the program would load the whole file into RAM, but it's only 69 MB. Perhaps it's also the effort of analysing the contents, but it still seems high to me. I'll try and break it apart as you suggest and see if that resolves my problem.

Comment: true, but the way the GUI displays it it also has to remember the colours for the text and all that comes with that, bearing in mind that IDLE itself is written in python, wheras i believe pythonwin is implemented in C so is more compact to begin with, meaning that it takes up less memory on its own

Comment: I split my single file out into four modules. Interestingly I cut the main file from 11k rows to 2.4k rows, but its size on disk went from 69MB to 2MB. It seems that after a certain row count a .py file really starts piling on the pounds.

Comment: thats strange, a .py file is just a text file though, there is no markup or anything special in there, its just basic characters. so am i right in assuming that the total size of all 4 modules is still 69MB? or is the sum of the parts smaller than that?

Comment: One of the sub files has about 3k rows but is ~64MB. I'm guessing there must some corruption going on.

Comment: sounds like it to me, try opening it with another text editor such as notepad++, as this shows all characters including non printable characters and gives the non printable characters special symbols, at least this way you could find any corruption and remove it http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: Yep, did just that earlier today. There was reems of gibberish in a couple of places. I've repaired it and it's all working as normal now. Thanks for your help.